# Avoiding null check when accessing an object property in java

Tags: java

I have a situation where I need get the property of a Java object if the object exists or null.

Something like `foo == null ? null : foo.bar`

Is there an operator available in java to do the same?

Comment: Programming with `null` leads to a lot of problems, this one included. Use `Optional` instead.

Comment: no operator available. you can do if- else instead. but the way you have written looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no *propagate null* operator in Java, cf. C# for example, which does have one. (It was a proposal at some point in Java's evolution, but has not sadly yet been incorporated into the language: `foo = foo?.bar` would be an obvious notation.)

You need to write this out longhand, as you have done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. _Null Propagation operator_ was the keyword I was missing.